# What are the different methods to upload image from iOS app

Tags: ios

I have tried with BLOB, base 64 using post methods to upload image .But not getting any success.

**Client side code**

```
    NSData *data = nil;

    NSString *imageData = nil;
    if (insertimageview.image != nil) {
    UIImage *image = insertimageview.image;
    data = UIImagePNGRepresentation(image);
    imageData = [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:0];
    #pragma  post method 
    NSString *url=@"http://localhost/rk.php";

    NSMutableURLRequest *thereq=[NSMutableURLRequest
requestWithURL:[NSURL URLWithString:url]    cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy timeoutInterval:60.0];
   [thereq setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
   NSString *post = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"sr=%@",imageData];
   NSData *postdata=[post dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
   [thereq setHTTPBody:postdata];
```

**Server side code**

```
<?php
$host="localhost"; // Host name
    $username="root"; // Mysql username
    $password=""; // Mysql password
    $db_name="q"; // Database name


    mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect");
    mysql_select_db("$db_name")or die("cannot select DB");
     $cat=$_POST["sr"];
        $catt="rrrrrr";
$img = @imagecreatefromstring(base64_decode($cat));
        if($img != false){
            imagejpeg($img, "htdocs/".$catt."");
        }
        else {
       echo falsss;
}

$qu="INSERT INTO q(id,q)VALUES(6,'$catt')";
$res=mysql_query($qu);
if($res){
echo "success";
}
else{
echo "mahender".mysql_error();
}
    ?>
```

Please help here or give me other possible solution to upload image.

Comment: What does "not getting any success" mean?  Are you getting any error conditions on the client?  Are you seeing the requests on the server?  Are you getting any errors on the server?

Comment: I am not getting any error but it is not storing into database @Droppy

Comment: So you are seeing the requests arrive at the server?